# Regex: Character set with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible for a regex character set (`[abc]`) to have characters with special meanings (like `$` for end of the line)? For example, is it possible to make a characters set that matches either a `/` or the start of the line `^`?

I tried `/[^\/]/g` but it just checks for a literal `^` or a `/`.

> Note: I'm using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't create custom special meaning, but you can be clever about the way you use the regex.

When doing complicated regex I test if any of these special characters exist in the string I'm testing -

```js
const str = '¡¢my string <>some content <>between</> fragment</> and other data...'
const markers = ['\u00A1','\u00A2','\u00A4']; //    ['¡','¢','¤'] you can add others
const safeMarker = markers.find(marker => str.indexOf(marker) === -1) // ¤ - this is not in the string so I can use it as a marker
if (safeMarker) {
  const replaced = str.replace(/<\/>/g, safeMarker); // output = 'my string <>some content <>between¤ fragment¤ and other data...'
  // do something with this regex and so on...
  // then replace the string back
}
```

The beauty of this is that you can convert any combination of characters into a single marker, which means you can use it in your Negation expression like this:

```js
/<>[^\u00A4]*\u00A4/g
```

Which would have been equivalent to (ie get the content between the tags)

```
<>[^</>]*</>
```